# XSLT Addenda Namespaces CFDI

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have the next addenda:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:ecfd="http://www.southconsulting.com/schemas/strict">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="cfdi:Addenda">
        <xsl:element name="requestForPayment">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">SimpleInvoiceType</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="contentVersion">1.3.1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="documentStructureVersion">AMC7.1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="documentStatus">ORIGINAL</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="requestForPaymentIdentification">
                <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is in the node:

```
<xsl:element name="cfdi:Addenda">
```

because when i run the addenda the namespace:

```
xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
```

it`s puts in the position of the node and i dont need this namespace in this place.
Of this way:

```
<cfdi:Addenda xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"></cfdi:Addenda>
```

and i need of this way:

```
<cfdi:Addenda></cfdi:Addenda>
```

any suggestions?????

*I try add the next instructions:*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:ecfd="http://www.southconsulting.com/schemas/strict" exclude-result-prefixes="cfdi">

<xsl:element name="cfdi:Addenda" namespaces="">
```

and this instruction works, but when this XSLT template will capture an XML document deletes the node start, being as follows:

```
<Addenda></Addenda>
```

**OUTPUT with this XSLT(i dont want this):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Addenda xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
    <requestForPayment type="SimpleInvoiceType" contentVersion="1.3.1" documentStructureVersion="AMC7.1" documentStatus="ORIGINAL">
        <requestForPaymentIdentification>1</requestForPaymentIdentification>
    </requestForPayment>
</cfdi:Addenda>
```

**I hope something like this:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Addenda>
    <requestForPayment type="SimpleInvoiceType" contentVersion="1.3.1" documentStructureVersion="AMC7.1" documentStatus="ORIGINAL">
        <requestForPaymentIdentification>1</requestForPaymentIdentification>
    </requestForPayment>
</cfdi:Addenda>
```

Comment: If **cfdi:Addenda** is the root element then you will need the namespace declaration on it, otherwise it won't be valid XML.

Comment: Could you help me please? with the sintaxis??

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a small, but complete, sample of your XML, and the output you actually expect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't produce the output you're looking for using XSLT because it is not namespace-well-formed, and XSLT always operates on namespace-well-formed XML. If you want to use a prefixed element name then the serializer *must* add the appropriate namespace declaration in order to produce legal output.

Even if there were a way to produce that output I'd still strongly advise against it because any other XML tool that tries to consume the data will complain about the undeclared namespace.

Comment: Im sorry but you have the reason